# Loading dub when click 'href' tag in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> I am a new user on stackoverflow. I have Issue in this question. Please help... I not found any post which related my question here since please don't mark it as duplicate or spam.

**Thank you in advance**

I have a script, When I hit on that the loading + overley show but only on when I click a submit buttons.When I make simple button & `href` tag then it is not working. I also try to change some script inside my js file. But nothing happen.

Overall on stackoverflow anyone is available who tell me how we solve this issue that I want when I click `a href` tag or `button` or `submit button` show loading or overley.

My js File is : https://pastebin.com/htyu68Cc
My Css File is : https://pastebin.com/q7VMpiLJ

Comment: It looks like you're only showing the overlay when the form's `submit` event is fired. If you want to show it when a button is clicked, you'll need to listen for the button's `click` event.

Comment: I only want when I press any link, button, input show that loading + overlay. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this.
Add following events under the form submit event in your javascript file and replace  '#buttonId', '#linkId', '#inputId' with your id.

for button

```
$('#buttonId').off().on('click', function () {
      $('#overlay, #loading').show();
        return true;
 });
```

for link

```
 $('#linkId').on('click', function () {
      $('#overlay, #loading').show();
      return true;
});
```

for input change

```
$(document).on('change', '#inputId input', function () {
      $('#overlay, #loading').show();
      return true;
});
```

Comment: Can I add all script one by one in my Js File? For works? Is there any id or class is required to do these action?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to #pritam Jyoti Ray 
Who helped me..

Code is working..